# Difference between Enum.values() and enumValues() in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, enums

In the [official document](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html#working-with-enum-constants), I found `enumValues()` function.

I used `enumValues()` function, but I cannot find difference.

```
enum class RGB {
    RED, GREEN, BLUE
}

RGB.values().joinToString { it.name } // RED, GREEN, BLUE
enumValues<RGB>().joinToString { it.name } // RED, GREEN, BLUE
```

What difference between `enumValues()` and `Enum.values()`?

Is it a function for platforms other than JVM? Or are there other use cases?

Comment: In the same documentation you mentioned it's specified that since Kotlin 1.1, it's possible to access the constants in an enum class in a generic way, using the `enumValues<T>()` and `enumValueOf<T>()` functions. `EnumClass.values()` is still used and has the same operational meaning, read above the `enumValues()`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem with `values()` is that it only exists on each concrete enum class, and you can't call it on a generic enum to get its values, which is quite useful in some cases. Taking just the simplest example of wanting to access all values in a `String`, `enumValues` lets you write a function like this:

```
inline fun <reified T: Enum<T>> getEnumValuesString(): String {
    // could call RGB.values(), but not T.values()
    // even with the generic constraint and reified generics

    // this works, however
    return enumValues<T>().joinToString()
}
```

Which can then be called with any enum class you've defined:

```
getEnumValuesString<RGB>()
```

Comment: But how does this work, compiler magic? Since the values array is physically on the concrete enum, isnt it?